# suggested edit review : what has been edited in this question?

Tags: discussion

I dont understand what was the edit suggested in this question : https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/7240922

By the way this question seems a good candidate for a close vote, why can't we vote to close directly from the review queue ?

Comment: ah I got it, the C tag was removed (red cross), got to buy some glasses ...

Comment: That edit should have been rejected, as it missed other, more pressing problems.